# Find columns where values are greater than column-wise mean

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, header, row

How to print the column headers if the row values are greater than the mean value (or median) of the column.

For Eg., 
`df =
         a    b     c    d
    0   12   11    13    45
    1   6    13    12    23
    2   5    12    6     35`

```
the output should be 0: a, c, d. 1: a, b, c. 2: b.
```

Comment: Can you please confirm what it is you _actually_ what? Do you want a dataframe of values or is just a simple list of tuples what you need?

Comment: A simple list of tuple with column headers. Thanks for clarifying it.

Comment: In that case, the answer you accepted gives you something else. Can you please look again?

Comment: Look at my answer and piRSquared's answer, if you want a list of tuples. Please be more careful when accepting an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [22]: df.gt(df.mean()).T.agg(lambda x: df.columns[x].tolist())
Out[22]:
0    [a, c, d]
1       [b, c]
2          [d]
dtype: object
```

or:

```
In [23]: df.gt(df.mean()).T.agg(lambda x: ', '.join(df.columns[x]))
Out[23]:
0    a, c, d
1       b, c
2          d
dtype: object
```

Comment: I need to recheck the pandas' handbook...even do not know `gt` :) Thank you~

Comment: @Wen, yeah, Pandas API is __huge__.  I'm always finding some methods that i didn't know before... ;-)

Comment: This is great, I was stuck at the df with booleans :)

Comment: Man, your guys' answer rly help me a lot ~

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, why do you think it's an overkill?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this by using `pandas` , I break down the steps

```
df=df.reset_index().melt('index')
df['MEAN']=df.groupby('variable')['value'].transform('mean')
df[df.value>df.MEAN].groupby('index').variable.apply(list)

Out[1016]: 
index
0    [a, c, d]
1       [b, c]
2          [d]
Name: variable, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `df.apply` to generate a mask, which you can then iterate over and index into `df.columns`:

```
mask = df.apply(lambda x: x >  x.mean())
out = [(i, ', '.join(df.columns[x])) for i, x in mask.iterrows()]
print(out)
[(0, 'a, c, d'), (1, 'b, c'), (2, 'd')]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
d = defaultdict(list)
v = df.values
[d[df.index[r]].append(df.columns[c])
 for r, c in zip(*np.where(v > v.mean(0)))];
dict(d)

{0: ['a', 'c', 'd'], 1: ['b', 'c'], 2: ['d']}
```